# Powershell get the Average value in Excel

Tags: powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have an Excel file with 3 columns

```
Date    MBytes  Percent  
Date1   1600    60         
Date2   1500    50         
Date3   1800    80       
Date4   800     20         
Date5   60      10
```

I would like to find the Average of Mbytes and the Percent column.
Also would like to know if Percent Average is above 80.. put a comment.

Answer (score 0):

First, initialize the com object, open the file, and select the sheet:

```
PS> $excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
PS> $wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\somewherepath\Book1.xlsx")
PS> $ws = $wb.sheets.item("Sheet1")
```

Set the range and get the average for "MBytes":

```
PS> $range = $ws.Range("b2", "b6")
PS> $excel.WorksheetFunction.AVERAGE($range)
1152
```

Set the range and get the average for "Percent":

```
PS> $range = $ws.Range("c2", "c6")
PS> $excel.WorksheetFunction.AVERAGE($range)
44
```

Determine if the avg percent is greater than 80

```
PS> $pctavg = $excel.WorksheetFunction.AVERAGE($range)
PS> $pct -gt 80
False
```

Comment: im getting the error below...
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ $excel.WorsheetFunction.AVERAGE($range)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: @uNoKaWaL Hmmmm... not sure.  The lines in the solution are copied directly from my PowerShell console.  As you can see, I'm not seeing that error.